SauceLabs and Python SSL Certificate issues
My company cert lives in C:
Python Selenium scripts are configured to plug into SauceLabs account and run webdriver
 # Point Python's certificate handling to certificate
os.environ['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = 'C:\\Users\\test\\.certificates\\CA.pem'

# Setting up Sauce Labs capabilities
sauce_options = {
    "username": "ProdTest",
    "accessKey": "xxxx",
    "appiumVersion": "2.1.3",
    "build": "test1",
    "name": "Health Test - Windows 11"
}

chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.set_capability('browserVersion', 'latest')
chrome_options.set_capability('platformName', 'Windows 11')
chrome_options.set_capability('sauce:options', sauce_options)

# URL for Sauce Labs
url = "https://ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub"


# Initialize the remote WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=url, options=chrome_options)

I repeatedly get SSL Cert errors
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1000)')))

I can connect to it fine like so from our work network.
import ssl
import urllib.request as request

# Point to cert
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile='C:\\Users\\test\\.certificates\\CA.pem')

try:
    with request.urlopen('https://ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com', context=ssl_context) as response:
        print('SSL Connection Successful:', response.read())
except Exception as e:
    print('SSL Connection Failed:', e)

Any ideas?
